# Data not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I have a link which links to a page which echoes out information depending on the id of the link but it is not echoing out the information. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
if($connect) {
            mysql_selectdb('phplogin');
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE id = '$id'");
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

           echo "<div class='post'>" . "<div class='leftside'>" . "<h3 class='by'>" . $data['user'] . "</h3>" . "<h5 class='date'>" . $data['time'] . "</h5>" . "</div>" . "<div class='after'>" . "</div>" . "<div class='rightside'>" . "<h2 class='title'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . "</h2>" . "<p class='description'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['description']) . "</p>"  . "</div>" . "<div class='clear'>" . "</div>" . "</div>";

        } else {
            die ('failed to connect to database');
        }
```

Comment: resource(3) of type (mysql link)

Comment: var_dump($connect) output ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: I have never heard of mysql_selectdb maybe replace with mysql_select_db('phplogin', $connect); works better.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and unsafe. I'd advise to use PDO instead. About your issue : do a var_dump on $data and see what values it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under this Query String: localhost/Website/HTML/Post.php?id=7

**Try this:**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
     $id       = $_GET['id'];
     $query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE id = '$id'");
     $countQry = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if($countQry>0)
     {
          $data     = mysql_fetch_array($query);
          //-- Fetch your Data here ---//
     }
     else
     {
          echo "No record found.";
     }
}
else
{
     echo "Invalid Id";
}
```

Your MYSQL Connection should be like this :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: this gives me invalid id

Comment: Can you provide me your query string ?

Comment: I think you mean this
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE id = '$id'");

Comment: No no. The link from your address bar

Comment: Try this link : localhost/Website/HTML/Post.php?id=7

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in "file path" on line 47
No record found.

Comment: i have a collumn for id, title, description, post, user and time

Comment: provide me your connection file

Comment: the file where you have made a connection with your database+mysql

Comment: i don't have a connection file its just 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123");
$mysql_select_db('phplogin');

Comment: it works and i have added the things it should do but it says that $id 
is an undefined index

Comment: Are you using this query string : localhost/Website/HTML/Post.php?id=7

Comment: sorry just got back and no i was not it works now with that thanks for all the help aswell as the better way to connect, but one question how do i include that so i dont have to include that everytime like just externalize it and call it when needed.

Comment: Just make a php file. place your connection code in it, and include it on top of every page . Very simple.